# Is being $O(x^2)$ implies being $O(x^3)$?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Is begin $O$(lower order polynomial) necessarily implies being $O$(higher order polynomial)? For example, does $f\in O(x^2)\Rightarrow f\in O(x^3)$ as $x\to c$, **for every** $c\in\Bbb R$ or $c=\pm\infty$? I feel that in the interval $(0,1)$, $x^3<x^2$, so there may be some exceptions?

Comment: Your question swaps low and high degrees randomly. Fix this.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for reminding. Forget to correct one place. Now edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asymptotic notation should always be stated with the limiting regime in mind. Both statements below are true-
$$ x^2 = O(x^3) \quad (x\to\infty)$$
$$x^3 = O(x^2) \quad (x\to 0)$$
with the reverse inclusions not true. 
In addition, for any $c\in \mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$, for any $\alpha\in\mathbb R$
$$ |x|^\alpha = O(1) \quad (x\to c)$$

Comment: Is $|x|^\alpha = O(1) \quad (x\to c)$ because in some neighborhood of c: $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$, we know by EVT that $x\mapsto |x|^{\alpha}$ is bounded on $[c-\delta,c+\delta]$, hence $|x|^\alpha\leq M|1|$ for all $x\in (c-\delta,c+\delta)$?

Comment: @Eric that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

No, let $x^2 \in O(x^2)$ as $x \to 0$. Suppose that there exists some $M$ so that

$x^2 \leq Mx^3$ as $x \to 0$. Then $\frac{1}{x} \leq M$, but as $x\to 0$, the LHS is unbounded.

Comment: So is there any relationship between being $O(x^2)$ and $O(x^3)$?

Comment: It depends. if $x \to \infty$ is of interest, then $O(x^2) \implies O(x^3)$, and if $x \to 0$, then Tsemo's example is true as well. $O$ should be thought of as a growth function. Growing at most quadratically surely means that a function is growing at most cubically. Likewise, as $x \to 0$, my first statement holds as well.

Comment: Well, seems that as $x\to c\in (0,1), f\in O(x^3)\Rightarrow f\in O(x^2)$, etc. And $x\to c\in (1,\infty), f\in O(x^2)\Rightarrow f\in O(x^3)$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)\le cx^2$ for all $x\ge x_0$, then $f(x)\le cx^3$ for all $x\ge \max(1,x_0)$, so that $O(x^2)\subset O(x^3)$. Because $x\ge1\implies cx^2\le cx^3$.